# SignalR - authenticate windows forms user on windows forms server

Tags: c#, windows, forms, signalr

I have a small project which contains a windows forms signalr client and a windows forms server. Clients can connect to server. Now, I want to implement a login system. I read some blogposts, articles and questions about this, but I didn't found a way to do it.  I would like to use the signalr authentication system so I can use attributes such as [Authorize] because it's already there.

To use this, I need to validate the username and password. Can the client sends the credentials in header like this

```
Connection = new HubConnection(BaseEngine.ServerURI);
Connection.Headers.Add("Username", username);
Connection.Headers.Add("Password", password);
HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");
await Connection.Start();
```

and the server should validate those credentials somehow in a method and throw an exception if are not valid?

I've tried to use the builtin system, but no luck. I couldn't obtain the Context.User in OnConnected method. As a workaround, I've tried to send the username and password in header and validate them, but the OnConnected method cannot throw errors to client. I am sure the client has to have an auth cookie, but I really don't know how to add it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found something like a workaround**: first of all, I implemented an attribute, derived from AuthorizeAttribute used by SignalR. This implementation overrides the AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation method witch is called when a method that is decorated with this attribute is called. So, in this method, I'm checking that an Authorization Token is present in the header of the request and validate the information. The client has to add this header to connect to the server. It's the easiest method I have found so far, but it's still an workaround.

Implementation, server:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
internal class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext, bool appliesToMethod)
    {
        string token = hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.Headers["AuthenticationToken"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            return false;
        else
        {
            string decryptedValue = Encryptor.Decrypt(token, Encryptor.Password);

            string[] values = decryptedValue.Split(';');

            string userName = values[0],
                deviceId = values[1];

            bool b = ...check if it's ok...

            return b;
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation, client:

```
 ComEngine.Connection = new HubConnection(BaseEngine.ServerURI);

 ComEngine.Connection.Headers.Add("AuthenticationToken", Encryptor.Encrypt(string.Format("{0};{1};{2}", BaseEngine.UserName, BaseEngine.DeviceId, BaseEngine.Password), Encryptor.Password));

 try
 {
     await Connection.Start();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good idea to send password to the server this way , it is better to send a token that the server can validate .

also SignalR has some authentication features read more about this [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization)

Comment: Hi! I'm sending the password to server encrypted. As an workaround, in the header is a combination between username, password and device id, all encrypted. I read everything from the link you posted, but I didn't found any way to create that cookie. The client is a windows forms application, the server too, not an asp.net website.